# Entity Framework 6.1.1 disable model compatibility checking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application

I am running into the following error after updating EF to version 6.1.1:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The model backing the `TvstContext` context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

We could fix this in the past as described in this question: 
[Where is modelBuilder.IncludeMetadataInDatabase in EF CTP5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484592/where-is-modelbuilder-includemetadataindatabase-in-ef-ctp5)

However, I can't seem to get rid of the error.

Comment: Did you enable the AutomaticMigrations? Or are you using manual migrations? If latter, did you try creating a new migration?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This should work, put it somewhere in the constructor of your derived DbContext:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

Comment: Thanks. I find that EF gets model change tracking corrupted in some cases (e.g. lots of model and migration changes during refactoring for the best solution), and the only way to fix it is to manually roll back changes and delete the stuck migrations from migrationhistory table.This EF model change tracking can be really annoying sometimes. Laravel has migrations, but no model tracking, and it works just fine. I guess, that's the price for model tracking - additional complexity and issues when you want to fight against EF automatic tracking, so sometimes it's better to turn it off completely.

Comment: Thanks. I dont need model changes tracking for my requirements. It just do the trick.

Comment: After far too many hours of this not working I found that I also had to update the EF config section in my web.config. I removed all settings from the context node and included disableDatabaseInitialization="true" on it. That's when it all started to work correctly. More info on that setting is at the bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606

Comment: this didn't work in the constructor. I just put it somewhere else in my code

Comment: Will this still work with add-migration and update-database commands if I decide to write my own migrations as SQL raw commands but still using EF migration management tools ignoring the model consistency issues?

Answer (score 24):

You can also set it in `Web.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>    
    <add key="DatabaseInitializerForType YourNamespace.YourDbContext, AssemblyName"
            value="Disabled" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Decision from:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/turn-off-database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: This works and is arguably preferred, since no code changes are required and the compatibility check can be turned on/off depending on environment etc.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Dabblernl's answers:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
    }
```