# What is the workflow in code-first EF to update database models without breaking published site?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Let's say I have a simple site with one context

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
   {
       public DbSet<Stuff> Stuff { get; set; }          
   }
```

and one model

```
 public class Stuff 
  {
   public int ID {get;set; }
   public string Name {get;set;}
 }
```

And I'm using code-first EF model, and I hit update-database and it creates my tables and then I publish my site. Everything is great. However, then I decide I want to add a property to my model

```
public class Stuff 
  {
   public int ID {get;set; }
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int StuffType {get;set;}
 }
```

And now I hit update-database and it updates the database with the new property, **but** the published site is now broken because its model is out of date with the database model.

Other than frantically trying to republish the site before anyone notices, is there any other way work with code-first migrations *without* breaking a published site?

Do I need to have two databases? If so, how do I then maintain the models between the two? This is further compounded by the fact that I usually have (at least) two git branches, and the published site is running the code from the master branch and I'm working on a develop branch - which is where I'd be modifying my models.

What is the usual workflow for avoiding these sorts of problems?

Comment: Well, yeah, you generally want at least 2 databases (DEV and PROD). Do all your DEV work then when you want to release do your publish and update the database with either a migration generated script or have your build server or Azure run them or build it into your app startup. http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the database initializer for your DataContext.
See this answer [Entity Framework 6.1.1 disable model compatibility checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860910/entity-framework-6-1-1-disable-model-compatibility-checking)